# PHP, looping through query results in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently having trouble trying to create a loop for my desired outcome.

I'm currently creating a student record card which stores numerous data of different students (fake students).

I have created a query which returns the relevant data I need (see picture one, phpmyadmin)

```
SELECT mods.mid, mtitle, credits, enrl.ayr 
FROM stud, smod, mods, enrl 
WHERE stud.sid = '154279' AND stud.sid = smod.sid 
AND smod.mid = mods.mid AND stud.sid = enrl.sid 
ORDER BY `enrl`.`ayr`  DESC
```

As you can see by the results, there are attributes: 
mid 
 
mtitle 
 
credits 
 
ayr

I have ordered by ayr in decending order. I am trying to make a loop that will run through the return on this query and print out each row until the end of whatever the current year is. Almost grouping all rows with the same year e.g. '2001/02' into a sub table which I can then name and print.

As you can see by my second picture of the student records page, I need to be able to print all records for the one year, then create a new header for the next existing year and print all containing rows for that.

{EDIT} 
PHP Code:

```
$query = "SELECT mods.mid, mtitle, credits, enrl.ayr 
            FROM stud, smod, mods, enrl 
            WHERE stud.sid = '154279' AND stud.sid = smod.sid AND smod.mid = mods.mid AND stud.sid = enrl.sid 
            ORDER BY enrl.ayr  DESC
        ";


$scap = ''; 
$curYear = $row['ayr'];  
if($result = $link->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc() && $row['ayr'] == $curYear) { 
            $scap .= "<table id=\"test\" style=\"width:100%\"> 
                        <tr> 
                            <td> " . $row['mid'] . " </td> <td> " . $row['mtitle'] . "</td> <td> " . $row['credits'] . " <td> " . $row['ayr'] . "</td>
                        </tr> 
                </table>"; 
        }$result->free(); 
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: I'm not sure, too what?

Comment: do you have any code to post??

Comment: Try adding some PHP. What have you tried so far?

Comment: you aren't descibing the date part well at all. It's in your head pretty well. But not over here anywhere

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: I know i'm frustrating myself. Basically, as you can see by the picture of the query return, if you look at the ayr data, it consists of the strings "1999/00" and "2000/01" 

What i'm trying to do, is make some sort of loop that will keep checking the ayr and as long as the date is the same, keep printing each row UNTIL the loop notices the date has changed, which will then start a new loop containing information with the new same date. If that makes sense?

Comment: or a new html separation

Comment: Yes, because as you can see by the second picture, all the modules for the 1 year, are stored in their own table

Comment: `I am trying to make a loop that will run through the return on this query and print out each row until the end of whatever the current year is.` That is what stumped me because here it is. You get everything in one query. All of it. In descending order like you are. Then, in the php loop, when the year / term thing changes from last one, create a new separation

Comment: I dont follow? @Drew

Comment: do a refresh of the page

Comment: because of what I put in blue above, and you showing data back to the year 2000, I was like huh? You only want `whatever the current year is`. and I was a dumb little rubber duck.

Comment: I would have a variable, call it $curYear. Start it out as some junk string. In your loop, if the cur year thing is **different** than $curYear, create a new segment in your output but regardless update $curYear variable

Comment: Oh sorry by current year I ment whatever was contained within the first row. In this case, I want to be able to grab and store all info with ayr = 2000/01

and then grab and store all info with ayr = 1999/00

Comment: let's back up. What do you mean grab and store. It is already in a db. It is stored.

Comment: you don't need some sub table thing you are mentioning in the Q

Comment: I ment store as in print that selection into a table on a web page. Sorry, my bad

Comment: and you only need 1 query max. Your PHP sorts it out

Comment: @drew check my edited PHP code. Is this what you mean?

Comment: let me just create an answer. Happy to delete it at the end.

Comment: I've made pseudo code to try and help explain myself. @Drew

// create temp variable 
// set $row['ayr'] to temp variable 
// create loop and check each instance WHILE $row['ayr'] == $tempVar
// if no 
// store next variable as temp variable 
// run loop again with new $tempVar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you commit to one query max for the whole page. Like I said in comments

> I would have a variable, call it $curYear. Start it out as some junk
>   string. In your loop, if the cur year thing is different than
>   $curYear, create a new segment in your output but regardless update
>   $curYear variable

That was not meant to interfere with your existing source code (that much). It is just a sentinel to alert you to a year change (year/term whatever).

So it starts as some junk value, like "797fsdf*"

Now inside your while, remember, you have ALL the years coming in from that result set for all years.

Do what I said in that pink block above comparing that variable `$curYear` to

```
$row['ayr']
```

When those two values are different, time to do whatever HTML treatment you want (creating a new html table, a new div, who cares). Let's call this the **separation thing.**

Regardless, after you output the row, make sure you have set `$curYear` to `$row['ayr']`. Why is that important? Because the next loop you want to know if you need to do the **separation thing.**

The tricky part is if you are doing html tables, you have to close out the previous table (prior year) if you are not on your first year

Comment: Hi @drew would you check my updated PHP code in the Q specifically the while loop part. I have added an additional && condition which I think is what you're trying to tell me?

Comment: Not really. Are you trying to output this into html tables. One table per year?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i'm trying to achieve :)

Comment: I did a question/answer post a minute ago [Over Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929130) you might find useful. Too many questions get deleted from Day1 users that vanish. Hope it helps, and good luck.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot for your time! I'm going to give it a read tomorrow! Thanks a lot

Comment: My pleasure. Now change your username. You are allowed to ya know

Comment: @Drew Maybe *jonlovesmath* ;-) I kinda like "math" myself.

Comment: Yes it was nothing more than a typo, but I will change it :) Thanks again @drew